# C#: Reading the content of a file, which is embedded in a resource file

Tags: c#, .net, resources

How can I read a **text file**, which is embedded in a **resx file** with the help of the **ResourceManager** class?

Whats wrong with the following snippet?

```
ResourceManager resman = new ResourceManager("Mynamespace.RESXFileName", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
Stream stream = resman2.GetStream("ResourceName");
```

**stream is alway = null!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ResourceNamespace>.ResourceManager.GetString(<textresourcename>);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
        using (var resourceStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                    .GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        {
            if (resourceStream != null)
            {
                using (var textStreamReader = new StreamReader(resourceStream))
                {
                    text = textStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw (new MissingManifestResourceException(resourceName));
            }
        }
```

The resource name is determined by namespace and filename. Say file `MyTxt.txt` exists in the root of the project, which has default namespace `MyNs` then the resource name will be: `MyNs.MyTxt.txt`

EDIT

I should learn to read the question. I haven't tested but this should give you what you want:

```
    static object GetResxObject(string resxPathName, string resourceKey)
    {
        using (var resxReader = new ResXResourceReader(resxPathName))
        {
            return resxReader
                .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                .Single(d => string.Equals(d.Key,
                                           resourceKey))
                .Value;
        }
    }

    ...
    var myString=(string)GetResxObject(@"path\to\resx.resx","myStringKey");
```